# How to use array variable in regexp expression (TCL)

Tags: tcl

In the file I have something like this:

```
name(0) = 123
name(1) = 456
name(2) = 789
```

I want to write match string to array.

```
  for { set i 0 } { $i < 3 } { incr i } {
     regexp {name\($i\) =\s+(.*)} $line full($i) name($i)
  }
```

I don't know why regexp don't recognizes $i counter.
If I write:

```
     regexp {name\(0\) =\s+(.*)} $line full($i) name($i)
```

working but only for first counter.

Answer (score 1):

Braces in Tcl quote the string literally, so no variable substitution is done.  If you want variable substitution, use double quotes.  Since you are quoting a regular expression, the backslashes will need to be escaped.

Convert:

```
{name\($i\) =\s+(.*)}
```

To:

```
"name\\($i\\) =\\s+(.*)"
```

Or as DKF has suggested.  This makes it easier to see the regexp without all the backslashes

```
set pattern [format {name\(%d\) =\s+(.*)} $i]
regexp $pattern $line full($i) name($i)
```

References:  [Tcl syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), [regex syntax](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [format](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/format.htm)

Comment: It might be easier to use `subst` or `format` to build the regular expression.